How to disable an AWS Quicksight dataset or analysis?
Is it possible to disable the nightly refresh of a QuickSight dataset and/or its corresponding analysis? It would be unfortunate if the only way to do this is to delete the whole thing from the app.

It is possible to disable the refresh schedule from a dataset.
Go to Datasets -> The dataset you want to choose -> Refresh -> And under Schedules choose Delete from the Actions column.
